# NULL radio button value

Tags: php, html, e-commerce

On line 13 of my code, I am getting a NULL $NaN value. If I replace $_POST['amount'] with static integer, the code POST the correct value. But trying to add a little functionality, now I can't get data to pass???

http://i40.tinypic.com/34gxauw.png

```
<div id="container">
<?php
    require_once('stripe-php/lib/Stripe.php');
    $stripe = array(
    'secret_key' => 'sk_07C5ukIdqxyDGFqIKB8f7TXqGGyQt',
    'publishable_key' => 'pk_07C58BHnzuFYQr9AUoZD6SCLiwANw'
    );
    Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

    if ($_POST) {
        $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
            'card' => $_POST['stripeToken'],
            'amount' => $_POST['amount'],
            'currency' => 'usd'
        ));
        var_dump($_POST['amount']);
        $quotes = array(
            "Thank you for your purchase!",
            "Enjoy your experience with with us!"
        );

        echo "<h1>Here's your quote!</h1>";
        echo "<h2>".$quotes[array_rand($quotes)]."</h2>";
    }
    else {
?>

    <h2>TPC Holdings</h2>
    <h3>Select your campaign package!!</h3>

    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select your package</legend>
            <p>
                <label>Select your package</label>
                <input type = "radio"
                        name = "amount[]"
                        id = "sizeSmall"
                        value = "50"
                        checked = "checked" />
                <label for = "sizeSmall">$50.00</label>

                <input type = "radio"
                        name = "amount[]"
                        id = "sizeMed"
                        value = "75" />
                <label for = "sizeMed">$75.00</label>

                <input type = "radio"
                        name = "amount[]"
                        id = "sizeLarge"
                        value = "large" />
                <label for = "sizeLarge">$100.00</label>
           </p>
       </fieldset>
    </form>

    <form action="paybill.php" method="post">
        <script src="https://button.stripe.com/v1/button.js"
             class="stripe-button"
             data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
             data-amount="<?php echo $d_charge; ?>"
             data-description="TPC purchase"
             data-label="Buy"></script>
    </form>

<?php
  }
?>

</div><!-- #container -->
```

Comment: `NAN` should mean `Not A Number` - I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make `amount field` as an `array`
User will `select` only **one** from these.

Try this,

```
<p>
    <label>Select your package</label>
    <input type = "radio"
        name = "amount"
        id = "sizeSmall"
        value = "50"
        checked = "checked" />
    <label for = "sizeSmall">$50.00</label>

    <input type = "radio"
        name = "amount"
        id = "sizeMed"
        value = "75" />
    <label for = "sizeMed">$75.00</label>

    <input type = "radio"
        name = "amount"
        id = "sizeLarge"
        value = "large" />
    <label for = "sizeLarge">$100.00</label>
</p>
```

Comment: or if you do name it `amount[size]` and then reference it as `$_POST["amount"]["size"];`

Comment: same issue with amount or amount[] in the form.

Comment: @Orangepill I'm really stuck here.

Comment: I should be getting data from my radio button.

Comment: 'amount' => 50000' will send the value $500.00 to my gateway.  'amount' => $_POST['amount'], fails to receive the value from the radio button.

Comment: @Orangepill name = "amount" is what I have set in my form and 'amount' => $_POST['amount'] is what I have in my php to catch it. This 'should' work.

Comment: @user2598588 Just as a test try removing the $ from the labels... I'm wondering if the stripe api is picking up that as the price and trying to do a floatval on it... resulting in a NaN

Comment: Same $NaN with http://bpaste.net/show/115709/ $ removed from the labels. $_POST is a string and a static value 'does' work. I can see the payment hit the sandbox gateway. But using variable data borks, and everything should all be strings.  -> me = monkey + lightbulb

Comment: @Orangepill see, static value  http://bpaste.net/show/115714/   live here  http://178.79.189.224/dev/paybill.php

Comment: post the code where you assign $dcharge in  billpay2.php... that is where your problem is

Comment: @Orangepill $d_charged was completely removed and not the issue.

Comment: @Orangepill $d_charge was replaced with -> data-amount="$_POST['amount']"  and $d_charge was only put there as a debugging attempt when data-amount="$_POST['amount']" failed for me at first.

Comment: make sure its being echoed in php tags...its not being parse on the link you sent

Comment: @Orangepill I do not know why it is not parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You NAN issue is coming from your `value="large"`.  It should be `value="100"` or whatever value you need it to be.  I can only assume, how the value is handled, that your handler is expecting a number and not a string.